# Kubernetes Go client library make it ignore SSL issues

Tags: go, kubernetes, kind

I am using Kind with docker-compose.

In my docker-compose file, I have the following line

```
extra_hosts:
  - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
```

This allows me to connect to Kind, which is running in localhost.

However, Kind only issue certificate to `localhost`, not to `host.docker.internal`.

I know that `kubectl` can ignore the certificate, but how to do the same with the Go client?

```
clientset := kubernetes.NewForConfigOrDie(ctrl.GetConfigOrDie())
```

The error

```
app-1       | panic: Get "https://host.docker.internal:33345/apis/apps/v1/namespaces/argo/deployments": x509: certificate is valid for kind-control-plane, kubernetes, kubernetes.default, kubernetes.default.svc, kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local, localhost, not host.docker.internal
```

Comment: what about adding `cluster:
    insecure-skip-tls-verify: true`  this in the config file?

Comment: It can be set directly in `Config.TLSClientConfig.Insecure`. Of course, if one feels so inclined, there's also a `NewForConfigAndClient` constructor. :-)

Comment: Adding insecure-skip-tls-verify: true causes

panic: specifying a root certificates file with the insecure flag is not allowed

Comment: @oakad I could not use this flag; I am not a go expert.